# Placing images in Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't place my images in column,i had tried my best but couldn't make it.
All my images are showing in rows.
 Here is my Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img id="img" src="img/homepage/images.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img2"src="img/homepage/images (1).jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img3"src="img/homepage/image3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
       </div>
  </div>
```

What's wrong i am doing? Here is the sample Image. I am newbie and wants to put more images in column too.

Comment: you want to put each image in a column, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your images are too wide for your column. Try putting them in separate columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img id="img" src="img/homepage/images.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img id="img2"src="img/homepage/images (1).jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img id="img3"src="img/homepage/image3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img id="img" src="https://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive img-rounded" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img id="img2"src="https://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive img-rounded" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img id="img3"src="https://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive img-rounded /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @Goran it worked . :)

Comment: How to resize each image width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to your img styles. Doing so makes img take up all horizontal space without scaling them up, so they stack up on top of each other.

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img id="img" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img2" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img3" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img id="img" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img2" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
      <img id="img3" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-xs-2.col-sm-6.col-md-4 {
 display: -moz-groupbox;
 display: table-caption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you missed a close tag

And i would like to suggest you that you should know about Bootstrap row and column.

Bootstrap count 12 column in a row.
[image]

As you like to set your image in many column of a row.So your code sholud like as,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="img" src="img/homepage/images.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="img2" src="img/homepage/images(1).jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="img3" src="img/homepage/image3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You So much That works too :)